# Google Geocoder different results between url and javascript requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm using component filtering with Google Geocoding to get data about a location. First I'm calling this link with a mispelled 'London' as 'Lindon' and nothing is returned. GOOD, I don't want it to find anything!

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:Lindon%7Ccountry:gb

But when I call it via javascript it returns 'London' data. I don't want it to, I want  it to NOT find it like in the URL request. Am I not using the Javascript call correctly? Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering) I used to program the call to google geocoder.

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: 'GB',
    locality: 'Lindon'
  }
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results.length >= 1) {
      for (var ii = 0; ii < results[0].address_components.length; ii++) {
        var street_number = route = street = city = state = zipcode = country = formatted_address = '';
        var types = results[0].address_components[ii].types.join(",");
        if (types == "street_number") {
          addr.street_number = results[0].address_components[ii].long_name;
        }
        if (types == "route" || types == "point_of_interest,establishment") {
          addr.route = results[0].address_components[ii].long_name;
        }
        if (types == "sublocality,political" || types == "locality,political" || types == "neighborhood,political" || types == "administrative_area_level_3,political") {
          addr.city = (city == '' || types == "locality,political") ? results[0].address_components[ii].long_name : city;
        }
        if (types == "administrative_area_level_1,political") {
          addr.state = results[0].address_components[ii].short_name;
        }
        if (types == "postal_code" || types == "postal_code_prefix,postal_code") {
          addr.zipcode = results[0].address_components[ii].long_name;
        }
        if (types == "country,political") {
          addr.country = results[0].address_components[ii].long_name;
        }
      }
      addr.success = true;
      //for (name in addr) {
      //    console.log('### google maps api ### ' + name + ': ' + addr[name]);
      //}
      response(addr);
    } else {
      response({
        success: false
      });
    }
  } else {
    response({
      success: false
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop phonetic matching with component filtering and restrictions with Google geocoder geocode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807941/stop-phonetic-matching-with-component-filtering-and-restrictions-with-google-geo)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's fairly simple (perhaps). Basically, order matters. Check out the difference:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=country:GB|locality:Lindon

vs

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:Lindon|country:GB

For the JS geocode, see

https://jsbin.com/furodil/edit?html,js,console,output

In my example JSBin here, the order is "wrong", and returns empty result; if you flip them, it returns the London partial match. You had your Web Service and JS Geocoder sending the components in different orders.

I think it has to do with the "components excluding itself" based upon a partial result. If you search `locality:Lindon` alone, it shows up as somewhere in the USA. Therefore, once you search that and THEN query for Great Britain, it will register that those two don't work together and will return a ZERO_RESULTS result. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering:

```
Component filtering will return a ZERO_RESULTS response only if you provide filters that exclude each other.
```

Lesson here seems to be: always go from the most general component to most specific.

Answer (score 1):

In results array, there's a partial_match field indicating that geocoder wasn't able to return an exact match for your request. You might want to use this. More details here:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results
```

I also created a JSFiddle to test this:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/k6yh2jLu/7/
```

Comment: I know about the partial match, but my question relates to why you get different results with the same input using two different methods to get geocoded results from google maps???

Comment: They return different results because the direct link (the one you posted) doesn't do partial matching.

Comment: That's not true though. The documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding indicates that web services support partial_match just like the Javascript APIs. Will need to look into this a bit more...

Comment: You're right!! It does do partial matching. My bad.